# xcode maven plugin unable to build library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to build my first iOS library using XCode Maven Plugin from scratch - for test purpose, only from resources added after choose 'Empty Application' from Xcode new project template. Below is my directory layout:

```
xcode-maven-hello-master
    pom.xml
    src
        xcode
            MavenTest
                AppDelegate.h
                AppDelegate.m
                MavenTest-Info.plist
                // other files (assets, etc.)
            MavenTest.xcodeproj
```

And there is my configuration file: (**pom.xml**)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>xcode-lib</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
                <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, my **artifactId** is the same as Xcode project name. Packaging is set to **xcode-lib**. I've also set extensions tag (**true**) and changed in XCode Preferences derived data folder relative to project folder with name **build**. But after invoking: **mvn clean install** I got following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.13.0:xcode-package
>   (default-xcode-package) on project MavenTest: Execution
>   default-xcode-package of goal
>   com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios:xcode-maven-plugin:1.13.0:xcode-package
>   failed:
>   /Users/kuba/Desktop/xcode-maven-hello-master/target/checkout/src/xcode/build/Release-iphoneos/libMavenTest.a
>   should be attached but does not exist

My library wasn't created. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If any of you have successfully built library and could explain me how to do it correctly? After invoking mvn install my library should be placed in local repository? I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try choosing an iOS static library project template instead of the empty application template if you want to create a library project. Could you try with this change?

Comment: You're right - it works when I created library project. But I think that it doesn't solve other problem - what if you want to include in your project some artifact as .framework file? And in another as static library (both from common sources)? Maybe you could configure separate target for each task and in your pom.xml file select appropriate target to compile, but I think that it should be guaranteed by plugin.

Comment: I did not get your question. But If u need the "artifact" for compiling, you could exclude it from the build target. By doing this, you compile the code, but the artifact is not included in the build.

Comment: [EDIT] *if you don't need

Comment: For example, you wrote your custom slide menu. In one project you want to include it as static library, but in another project you want to include it as .framework file. And my question was about how to do it :) My conclusion is that plugin should support it by choosing xcode-lib or xcode-framework as package type in each project's pom.xml that want include your slide menu. But template of your slide menu project shouldn't have matter.